# Get the first and last day of current month

Tags: date, go, time

I'm trying to get the first and last day of the current month. You can add days and hours but not the month, which I was thinking of subtracting one day from the next month to get the last day of this month. Something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    date := time.Now()
    nextMonth := date.Add(time.Month)
    LastDay := nextMonth.Add(-time.Hour * 24)

    fmt.Println(LastDay)

}
```

Comment: `LastDay` won't be right if there's a transition to or from DST in the last day of the month in your local timezone.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use **now** library, it really simple :

```
now.BeginningOfMonth()    // 2013-11-01 00:00:00 Fri
now.EndOfMonth()          // 2013-11-30 23:59:59.999999999 Sat
```

Please take a look here for detail : https://github.com/jinzhu/now

Comment: If you don't wanna use this library you can at least learn from the way it does (you can actually copy the parts that you need): https://github.com/jinzhu/now/blob/master/now.go

Comment: BUG ALERT: The [now package](https://github.com/jinzhu/now) does not give correct results during daylight saving transitions. It incorrectly assumes that there are always 24 hours in a day: `func (now *Now) BeginningOfMonth() time.Time`: `* 24 * time.Hour`.

Comment: @peterSO fixed that, sorry for the problem.

Answer (score 73):

`time.Month` is a type, not a value, so you can't `Add` it.  Also, your logic is wrong because if you add a month and subtract a day, you aren't getting the end of the month, you're getting something in the middle of next month.  If today is 24 April, you'll get 23 May.

The following code will do what you're looking for:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    currentYear, currentMonth, _ := now.Date()
    currentLocation := now.Location()

    firstOfMonth := time.Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, currentLocation)
    lastOfMonth := firstOfMonth.AddDate(0, 1, -1)

    fmt.Println(firstOfMonth)
    fmt.Println(lastOfMonth)
}
```

[Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/F7GoesAAcK)

Comment: Eventhough the question was only the first and last day it might be helpful to increase lastOfMonth by 23 hours, 59 minutes, 59 seconds and 999 millis. 

Like this:

 ```lastOfMonth = lastOfMonth.Add(time.Hour * 23)```
 ```lastOfMonth = lastOfMonth.Add(time.Minute * 59)```
 ```lastOfMonth = lastOfMonth.Add(time.Second * 59)```
 ```lastOfMonth = lastOfMonth.Add(time.Millisecond * 999)```

Answer (score 43):

Not sure when `AddDate(...)` was added to `time.Time`, but quite possibly it was added after this question had its prime time :)

Here's another way to achieving the same with `time.Time.AddDate(...)` -

```
func BeginningOfMonth(date time.Time)  (time.Time) {
    return date.AddDate(0, 0, -date.Day() + 1)
}

func EndOfMonth(date time.Time) (time.Time) {
    return date.AddDate(0, 1, -date.Day())
}
```

Then you could use `today := time.Now()` and pass it over to one/both of the functions like so - `eom := EndOfMonth(today)` to get the appropriate date.

If time, DST and such are important, it should be pretty straightforward to ornament those details on top of it once you get the date.

Finally, here's a playground link where you can play around with it - https://play.golang.org/p/DxnGuqh6g4k

Comment: This is by and far the most elegant approach.

Comment: Wonderful ... just in time when I was about to stop scrolling down since I though I already found a "good" approach :-)

Comment: This is excellent and seems to work for all cases.

Answer (score 24):

The [@Apin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36830416/221700) is dangerous because the **now** lib makes **many wrong assumptions** (it bit me in the foot too).
The now lib doesn't consider daylight saving times and many other things:
https://github.com/jinzhu/now/issues/13

This is how I'm doing it:

```
t := time.Now()
firstday := time.Date(t.Year(), t.Month(), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.Local)
lastday := firstday.AddDate(0, 1, 0).Add(time.Nanosecond * -1)
```

Comment: I added a BUG ALERT comment to [@Apin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36830416/221700) for you.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it like this:

```
// LastDayOfMonth returns 28-31 - the last day in the month of the time object
// passed in to the function
func LastDayOfMonth(t time.Time) int {
    firstDay := time.Date(t.Year(), t.Month(), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    lastDay := firstDay.AddDate(0, 1, 0).Add(-time.Nanosecond)
    return lastDay.Day()
}
```

a

Answer (score 5):

This can also be a solution:

```
currentTimestamp := time.Now().UTC()
currentYear, currentMonth, _ := currentTimestamp.Date()
currentLocation := currentTimestamp.Location()

firstOfMonth := time.Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, currentLocation)
lastOfMonth := time.Date(currentYear, currentMonth+1, 0, 23, 59, 59, 999999999, currentLocation)

fmt.Println(firstOfMonth)
fmt.Println(lastOfMonth)
```

Output:

```
firstOfMonth: 2019-11-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
lastOfMonth: 2019-11-30 23:59:59.999999999 +0000 UTC
```

Click here to try it out:
[Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/qcL6Tt6oe1j)

Answer (score 4):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> ```
> import "time"
> ```
>
> [func Date](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Date)
>
> ```
> func Date(year int, month Month, day, hour, min, sec, nsec int, loc *Location) Time
> ```
>
> Date returns the Time corresponding to
>
> `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss + nsec nanoseconds`
>
> in the appropriate zone for that time in the given location.
>
> The month, day, hour, min, sec, and nsec values may be outside their
>   usual ranges and will be normalized during the conversion. For
>   example, October 32 converts to November 1.
>
> A daylight savings time transition skips or repeats times. For
>   example, in the United States, March 13, 2011 2:15am never occurred,
>   while November 6, 2011 1:15am occurred twice. In such cases, the
>   choice of time zone, and therefore the time, is not well-defined. Date
>   returns a time that is correct in one of the two zones involved in the
>   transition, but it does not guarantee which.
>
> Date panics if loc is nil.

Month and day values outside their usual ranges will be normalized. For example, for the first and last day of the month time interval,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func monthInterval(t time.Time) (firstDay, lastDay time.Time) {
    y, m, _ := t.Date()
    loc := t.Location()
    firstDay = time.Date(y, m, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, loc)
    lastDay = time.Date(y, m+1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, loc)
    return firstDay, lastDay
}

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t.Round(0))
    first, last := monthInterval(t)
    fmt.Println(first)
    fmt.Println(last)

    dstLoc, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Los_Angeles")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    // Sunday, March 12, 2017, 2:00:00 am to Sunday, March 12, 2017, 3:00:00 am
    dstStart := time.Date(2017, 03, 12, 2+1, 0, 0, 0, dstLoc)
    // Sunday, November 5, 2017, 2:00:00 am to Sunday, November 5, 2017, 1:00:00 am
    dstEnd := time.Date(2017, 11, 5, 2-1, 0, 0, 0, dstLoc)
    t = dstStart
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println(t)
    first, last = monthInterval(t)
    fmt.Println(first)
    fmt.Println(last)
    t = dstEnd.Add(time.Hour)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println(t)
    first, last = monthInterval(t)
    fmt.Println(first)
    fmt.Println(last)
}
```

Output:

```
2017-10-27 05:45:08.197312082 -0400 EDT
2017-10-01 00:00:00 -0400 EDT
2017-10-31 23:59:59.999999999 -0400 EDT

2017-03-12 03:00:00 -0700 PDT
2017-03-01 00:00:00 -0800 PST
2017-03-31 23:59:59.999999999 -0700 PDT

2017-11-05 01:00:00 -0800 PST
2017-11-01 00:00:00 -0700 PDT
2017-11-30 23:59:59.999999999 -0800 PST
```

Answer (score 2):

goutils provides many useful func tools. [goutils](https://github.com/printfcoder/goutils)

```
beginningOfTMonth:=time.TimeBeginningOfMonth(t)
endOfTMonth:=time.TimeEndOfMonth(t)


beginningOfTWeek:=time.TimeBeginningOfWeek(t)
endOfTWeek:=time.TimeEndOfWeek(t)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
dd := time.Now()
firstDayOfCurrentMonth := time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -dd.Day()+1)
lastDayOfCurrentMonth := firstDayOfCurrentMonth.AddDate(0, 1, -1)
```

Explaination:

`dd.Day` will give the day from particular date ex: March 4, 2010. it will give 04 as day.

`AddDate` returns the time corresponding to adding the given number of years, months, and days to t. For example:
`AddDate(-1, 2, 3)` applied to January 1, 2011 returns March 4, 2010.

`AddDate` normalizes its result in the same way that Date does, so, for example, adding one month to October 31 yields December 1, the normalized form for November 31.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?